# Using exceljs and ran into memory leak while parsing large excel file

Tags: node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory, exceljs

We're using [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#writing-csv) library to parse a large excel file (75,000+ rows and 7 columns). We ran out of heap memory and have the following error

```
start of marking 1318 ms) (average mu = 0.160, current mu = 0.027) all[86559:0x102892000]    49646 ms: Mark-sweep 2033.6 (2064.5) -> 2025.1 (2058.0) MB, 1426.3 / 0.0 ms  (+ 103.0 ms in 30 steps since start of marking, biggest step 8.4 ms, walltime since start of marking 1533 ms) (average mu = 0.083, current mu = 0.002) allo[86559:0x102892000]    52226 ms: Mark-sweep 2026.9 (2058.0) -> 2024.5 (2056.0) MB, 2573.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.033, current mu = 0.003) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x100930c99]
Security context: 0x3041d3d408a1 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x3041d675cfb9] [/Users/kaisinli/Desktop/AVRA-Frontend/node_modules/exceljs/lib/doc/worksheet.js:~839] [pc=0xb256c553c70](this=0x304197ec04a9 <undefined>,0x30419afbb229 <Object map = 0x3041afdfe4b1>)
    2: forEach [0x3041d3d51319](this=0x304126bf7941 <JSArray[1001]>,0x3041d675cfb9 <JSFunction (sfi = 0x3041650ab709)>...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20210823.154747.86559.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
 1: 0x10007e9b3 node::Abort() [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
 2: 0x10007eb37 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
 3: 0x100176337 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
 4: 0x1001762d3 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
 5: 0x1002fa485 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
 6: 0x1002fbb54 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
 7: 0x1002f8a27 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
 8: 0x1002f6a0d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
 9: 0x100302124 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
10: 0x10030219f v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
11: 0x1002ced97 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
12: 0x1005f83e5 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
13: 0x100930c99 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/Users/kaisinli/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node]
```

What would be the best way to parse through large excel files without running out of memory? Our size is --max_old_space_size=16384